# Find a Specific String or Word in Files and Directories

Tags: linux, sed, grep

Need to find this string `"key" : "` recursively in all files in the current directory.

I used the below command and it didn't work.

```
grep -i -R " \"key\":\" " .
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the input, the desired output, and the exact meaning of "it didn't work".

Comment: An error message / description would be nice.

Comment: "key" : " is the input, and grep -i -R " \"key\":\" " / not printing any output

Answer (score 2):

That may be because `" \"key\":\" "` is not the pattern that represents `"key" : "`, as there's a space in the pattern before `\"key`. Try:

```
grep -i -R "\"key\":\" " .
```

Or to simplify it and make more readable:

```
grep -iR '"key" : ' .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -rl 'key" : ' {} +
```

Use `-r` instead of `-R`, because `-R` follows symlinks when descending directories, while `-r` doesn't.